# RegEx to replace special characters in a string with space ? asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

```
string inputString = "1/10 EP Sp'arrowha?wk XT R;TR 2.4GHz Red";
//Characters Collection: (';', '\', '/', ':', '*', '?', ' " ', '<', '>', '|', '&', ''')
string outputString = "1 10 EP Sp arrowha wk XT R TR 2.4GHz Red";
```

Comment: Are you trying to do some kind of escaping for SQL by any chance?

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but... this is a question? With 9 upvotes? Good god!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Full disclosure regarding the following code:

- It's not tested
- I probably messed up the character escaping in `new Regex(...)`;
- I don't actually know C#, but I can Google for `"C# string replace regex"` and [land on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx)

  ```
  Regex re = new Regex("[;\\/:*?\"<>|&']");
  string outputString = re.Replace(inputString, " ");
  ```

---

Here's the correct code:

```
string inputString = "1/10 EP Sp'arrowha?wk XT R;TR 2.4GHz R\\ed";
Regex re = new Regex("[;\\\\/:*?\"<>|&']");
string outputString = re.Replace(inputString, " ");
// outputString is "1 10 EP Sp arrowha wk XT R TR 2.4GHz R ed"
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/hrKdJ

Also: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Move the `'` inside the char class, also I'd use a `+`, like `"[;\\/:*?\"<>|&']+"`

Comment: @Matt Ball, I understand that you are probably upset that the OP didn't google first, but that doesn't mean you have to be mean or sarcastic.

Comment: @Xaisoft that was meant as a disclosure, no negativity intended at all. I've reworded it; please let me know if it still comes off badly.

Comment: @Matt Ball, its all good.  I didn't think you were being negative, I thought you were upset that people don't at least try before posting.

Comment: What if I wanted to replace [ and ]?

Answer (score 4):

```
string outputString = Regex.Replace(inputString,"[;\/:*?""<>|&']",String.Empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Java code to replace special characters

```
String inputString = "1/10 EP Sp'arrowha?wk XT R;TR 2.4GHz R\\ed";
String re = "[;\\\\/:*?\"<>|&']";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(re);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
String outputString = matcher.replaceAll(" ");
```