# Regular expression to extract items from a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

A pilot may enter their route of flight into a textbox as:

KRIC-KLAX - IAD / I69

This is extreme as it would normally be KRIC-KLAX-KIAD-I69.  The point is that each "fix" is separated by non a-z or 0-9 characters.  I need to extract the fixes out of the above string to come up with an array of fixes that would be:

KRIC,KLAX,IAD,I69

Anyone know the regular expression, preferably in .NET C# to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>var matches = Regex.Matches("KRIC-KLAX - IAD / I69", @"([\d\w]+)");</s>

Demo [here](http://rubular.com/r/BZDGedequM).

## UPDATE

```
 var matches = Regex.Matches("KRIC-KLAX - IAD / I69", @"(\w+)");
```

Comment: The `\d` there is not necessary because `\w` will match digits, letters, and underscores.  If you want to avoid underscore matching, you'll want this variation:  `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`

Comment: Awesome - thank you for the fast response and helpful site as well!

Comment: be warned that by default, on the server side, \w also includes all Arabic, Chinese, Greek, Latin etc characters. If you really want to be on the safe side here, I suspect that using [a-zA-Z0-9] is a lot better than \w. (See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx#ECMAScript)

Answer (score 2):

```
  var result = Regex.Matches(input, @"\w+")
      .OfType<Match>()
      .Select(_ => _.Value)
      .ToArray();
```

or even simpler:

```
  var result = Regex.Split(input, @"\W+").ToArray();
```

As @TLS correctly pointed out, if underscore should also be treated as delimiter, you'd probably use `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

Comment: `Matches` does not return `IEnumerable<T>`. You need to use `Cast<Match>`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do something like this:

```
string inputString = "KRIC-KLAX - IAD / I69";
Regex re = new Regex("[ /-]"); 
string outputString = re.Replace(inputString, ","); 
// outputString is "KRIC,KLAX,IAD,I69"
```

I just modified the code from the post [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049293/regex-to-replace-special-characters-in-a-string-with-space-asp-net-c-sharp)